# Can't get access to the port 3000 on the DO droplet

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I try to deploy react project and I am following [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) tutorial

I have installed `npm` and `nodejs` and executed 2 simple commands to start my firs project:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

After that I have accepted successful message to the console

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view my-app in the browser.

  http://localhost:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

I also added port 3000 to the firewall on the DO:

[image]

So, it seems all should works, but it isn't.
More of then - the ngnix started on the server and I able to open it on the port 80. but not `1.2.3.4:3000`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us your app code, but I think the key is in the message:

> You can now view my-app in the browser.
>
> http://localhost:3000

It's common in code samples to bind to `127.0.0.1` and/or `::1` by default, so as not to expose potentially broken app code to the world.

You should modify your code or otherwise configure it to listen on `0.0.0.0` or `::`, which indicates "all interfaces".

Comment: Thanks, but I can't image how to the code can influent on this issue. I have launched a lot of spring projects before on the AWS and as I clearly understood until now - if project works locally on the localhost:ANY_PORT it will work remotely on the x.x.x.x:ANY_PORT

Answer (score 0):

You should config reverse proxy in nginx port to access your application. Don't try open 3000 for issue security. This is simple reverse proxy config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain_name; #change to your domain name

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Save it to `default.conf` and reload nginx or create new `.conf` file.
So, you only access IP `1.2.3.4` to see your node application.

Comment: This configuration is really no more or less secure than allowing direct access to the application.